# How to handle created_by and updated_by columns for multi auth guards in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I'm using laravel 5.6 multi auth where i have 3 guards admins, professionals, users. I'm using this package https://github.com/richan-fongdasen/eloquent-blameable for created_by, updated_by fields.

I have articles table where admins can create a post and also professionals can create a post, which are viewed by the frontend users.

I have added the below code to the admin model and whenever i create a post the creared_by and updated_by(if i update) are filled in with the logged in admin user id.

```
public function blameable()
    {
        return [
            'user' => \App\Admin::class,
            'createdBy' => 'user_id',
            'updatedBy' => 'user_id'
        ];
    }
```

Now when i create a post from the professionals section i want the createdBy and updatedBy to be professional id. How to achieve this?

Do i need to create a separate model as professionalposts for the same table and use

```
public function blameable()
        {
            return [
                'user' => \App\Professional::class,
                'createdBy' => 'user_id',
                'updatedBy' => 'user_id'
            ];
        }
```

This is an important field as it
1. Displays the author name for the articles which makes users know who wrote the article.
2. Helps to list all the articles created by the professional in their dashboard.

I have different ideas in my head like created a extra column professional_id(nullable) which will be filled if posted from professional section and is set to null if posted from admin.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple library:

```
use Culpa\Traits\Blameable;
use Culpa\Traits\CreatedBy;
use Culpa\Traits\DeletedBy;
use Culpa\Traits\UpdatedBy;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model

class Comment extends Model
{
    use Blameable, CreatedBy, UpdatedBy;

    protected $blameable = array('created', 'updated', 'deleted');

    // Other model logic here
}
```

How to install:
https://github.com/nstapelbroek/culpa-laravel-5